# How to Remove a Attribute of a Property in a Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I want to do some changes in a table that is already exist(i am using sqlite). I want to remove a Attribute of a property in a class. Remove [Required] attribute. How can i do that, what should i change, should i some changes in DbContext or migration folder or what commands can i use in package manager console.

```
public class Appointment
    {
[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Company { get; set; }
```

Comment: did you try to remove the attribute and create a new migration?

Comment: Usually all that's required is to remove the attribute from the code, then migrate through EF. Does removing the line in your code that says `[Required]` and migrating cause any other issues?

Comment: When i remove it from code and make a new migration. In the package manager console there is a error as Appointments class already exist, now in database it is not null i want to make it null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of why it is better to use fluent API then attributes to specify your database: you want the same class to be used in a different database.

The DbContext defines the database: what tables are in it, how do the tables relate towards each other, what classes do represent the tables, and what are the constraints to the tables.

For instance, maybe in one database you want Company to have a MaxLength of 50 characters, in another database you might desire a length of 100 characters. Some databases need a simple DateTime, others require a DateTime2. Or maybe you want a different precision for your decimals?

Hence it is usually better to specify the database statistics where it belongs: in the definition of the database, which is the DbContext.

### Back to your question

It depends a bit on the entity framework that you are using on how the database reacts if during migration you use remove the Required attribute and move it to fluent API. I guess it is best to experiment with it.

In OnModelCreating, or the migration equivalent of it, you will have something like:

```
var entityAppointment = modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>();
var propertyCompany = entityAppointment.Property(appointment => appointment.Company);
propertyCompany.IsOptional()
               .HasMaxLength(50)
               ...; // other non-default specifications of Company
                    // like columnName, IsUnicode, etc
```

When migrating the statements might be little different, but I guess you get the gist.